# PHP readfile adds content length to output

Tags: php, readfile

I am using the PHP readfile function to read a file and print it like so: `print readfile ('anyfile')`. This works, but the content length of the file is added at the end of the string also. Why?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) prints out the contents itself and returns the content length -- you're effectively printing the contents with `readfile` and then printing the content length with `print`.  Remove print and just use

```
readfile('anyfile');
```

Comment: Ah, clarifying. Any idea why they made this function output two variables? Not very useful when you don't want to output something straight away.

Comment: @Derk, they didn't.  It outputs the file contents and returns the byte length.  There's a number of functions like this that write directly to the output buffer and there's usually a similar alternative.  One such alternative in this case might be `file_get_contents()`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "output it straight away", `readfile()` outputs -- writes to the output buffer -- the instant it is called/before it returns.

Comment: Well you might want to store the contents into a variable first. I'm using `readfile` because it doesn't use as much memory, as I read somewhere.

Comment: @Derk: `file_get_contents()` is what you need for performance and storing the contents into a variable: `file_get_contents() is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance.`

Comment: From a [thread](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/705790-file_get_contents-vs-readfile) with the same reference you make: "Actually, readfile doesn't read the whole file, it uses mmap if possible, otherwise reads/writes in 8K chunks, thus conserving memory."
Someone tried it with a 179MB file and the memory usage was 1.7MB. So, whatever fits the purpose.

Comment: @Derk: Good to know, but that was also my point.  If you want the contents in a variable, use `file_get_contents`, if you want to dump the contents without any manipulation use `readfile`.